# Why do I get different RandomForest outcomes between R and Python?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to compare the results of random forest model using R and using Python. The key measurement on model performance that I am comparing is AUC (the Area Under an ROC Curve). The reason for that is AUC value is representative of distribution of predicted values (i.e. probabilities). I did find some notable difference in AUC values between R and Python. I did read thru some related questions and answers on Stack Overflow regarding discrepancy between R and Python. However, I feel my problem should be different from those.

I tried to keep some key hyper-parameters the same in R and in Python. They are:

1. Set `ntree` in R equal to `n_estimators` in Python
2. Set `mtry` in R equal to  `max_features` in Python
3. Set `nodesize` in R equal to `min_samples_leaf` in Python
4. Set class weight as default value in R and in Python. In R, the default value is `NULL`. In Python, the default value is `None`.
5. Set sample size in R equal to total number of rows in training data, which is the default setting in Python.
6. Set `replace` in R equal to `bootstrap` in Python, i.e. both are `True` or both are `False`.

The problem is a two-class classification problem, with 86 predictors. Each of the predictors are either continuous or Boolean. There is no factor type predictor used in R. There are 2008 observations in training data, and 335 observations in testing data. The response rate in both data are same, i.e. 79.7%.

Results are as follows:

**Model 1 outcome in R**
`training_auc=0.9249080`, `test_auc=0.6308934`

**Model 2 outcome in R**
`training_auc=0.9245665`, `test_auc=0.6364838`

**Model 1 outcome in Python**
`training_auc=0.80515863`, `test_auc=0.62194316`

**Model 2 outcome in Python**
`training_auc=0.86075733`, `test_auc=0.61522362`

You can find the difference in AUC values in Model 2 (non-bootstrap sampling) between R and Python is smaller than in Model 1 (bootstrap sampling), especially in AUC on training data.

Why is there such huge difference in AUC on training data even if I set those hyper-parameters same in R and Python? Did I miss any important parameter? Or is there any mistake in my R or Python code?

### R Code for RandomForest Model

```
library(randomForest)
library(glmnet)
setwd("D:/Project Files2/Python Efficiency/test RF using another dataset")

#read in data for training and data for testing
X_train01 <- read.csv("X_train_0.csv",header=FALSE)
y_train01 <- read.csv("y_train_0.csv",header=FALSE)
colnames(y_train01) <- "response"

X_test01 <- read.csv("X_test_0.csv",header=FALSE)
y_test01 <- read.csv("y_test_0.csv", header=FALSE)
colnames(y_test01) <- "response"

#define a function for RF
run_quick_rf4 <- function(X_train01,y_train01, X_test01, y_test01, ntree, mtry, nodesize, maxnodes=NULL, replace=TRUE, classwt=NULL, rnd_seed= 12345){
  
  set.seed(rnd_seed)
  rf_model <- randomForest(x=X_train01,y=as.factor(y_train01[,1]),
                           ntree=ntree,
                           mtry= mtry,
                           nodesize= nodesize,
                           maxnodes= maxnodes,
                           replace = replace,
                           sampsize = nrow(X_train01),
                           classwt = classwt
  )
  train01_pred <- predict(rf_model, X_train01, type='prob')
  train01_auc <- auc(y_train01[,1], train01_pred[,2])
  
  test01_pred <- predict(rf_model, X_test01, type='prob')
  test01_auc <- auc(y_test01[,1],test01_pred[,2])
  auc_outcome<- c(train01_auc, test01_auc)
  names(auc_outcome)<- c("training_auc", "test_auc")
  return(auc_outcome)
}
#>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>End of this function>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

#run random forest models with parameters set.

#Model 1
run_quick_rf4(X_train01, y_train01, X_test01, y_test01, 500, 20, 20, maxnodes=NULL, replace=TRUE, classwt=NULL, rnd_seed= 12345)

#Model 2
run_quick_rf4(X_train01, y_train01, X_test01, y_test01, 500, 20, 20, maxnodes=NULL, replace=FALSE, classwt=NULL, rnd_seed= 12345)
```

### Python Code for RandomForest Model

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import datetime
import os
#change work directory
os.chdir("D:/yxue/Uplift_Gilenya/followup/Data")

# only specify sample weight
def run_quick_RF_final(file_counter, n_estimators, max_features, min_samples_leaf, max_leaf_nodes=None, class_weight={0: 1, 1: 1}, s_wt={0:1, 1:1}, bootstrap=True, random_seed=4568):
    
    x_train_file = 'X_train_%d.csv' %(file_counter)
    y_train_file = 'y_train_%d.csv' %(file_counter)
    x_test_file = 'X_test_%d.csv' %(file_counter)
    y_test_file = 'y_test_%d.csv' %(file_counter)
    
    X_train = np.loadtxt(x_train_file, delimiter=',', skiprows=0)
    y_train = np.loadtxt(y_train_file, delimiter=',', skiprows=0) 
    
    X_test = np.loadtxt(x_test_file, delimiter=',', skiprows=0)
    y_test = np.loadtxt(y_test_file, delimiter=',', skiprows=0) 
 
    rf_model = RandomForestClassifier()
    rf_model.set_params(n_estimators=n_estimators, max_features=max_features, min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf, max_leaf_nodes=max_leaf_nodes, class_weight=class_weight, criterion='gini', bootstrap=bootstrap, random_state=random_seed)

    if s_wt != None:
        sample_wt = np.ones((len(y_train),), dtype=np.float64)
        sample_wt[y_train == 0] = float(s_wt[0])
        sample_wt[y_train == 1] = float(s_wt[1])
    else:
        sample_wt = s_wt

    #print np.bincount(sample_wt)
    rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight=sample_wt)
    
    pred_train = rf_model.predict_proba(X_train)
    train_auc = roc_auc_score(y_train,pred_train[:, 1])
    
    pred_test =  rf_model.predict_proba(X_test)
    test_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, pred_test[:, 1])
    
    auc_outcome = np.array([train_auc, test_auc])
    
    return auc_outcome
    
# run random forest model. the parameter setting is same as in R
# Model 1
run_quick_RF_final(0, 500, 20, 20, max_leaf_nodes=None, class_weight=None, s_wt=None, bootstrap=True, random_seed=4568)

# Model 2
run_quick_RF_final(0, 500, 20, 20, max_leaf_nodes=None, class_weight=None, s_wt=None, bootstrap=False, random_seed=4568)
```

Comment: This might be more suited for code review...

Comment: How can you be sure the difference is not due to randomness? Did you check the distribution of AUC?

Comment: @Heroka Thank you for your reply! Any more specific suggestion is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: @DavidH thanks for your comment. I did re-run the models in r and in python several times. I did change the random seed number each time. But new AUC values are very close to what you saw in my article. That means the difference between R and Python may not be really caused by the ramdomness. Any other insight or suggestion will be welcome and be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the tree-criterion for splitting in randomForest in R is "gini" and not entropy ? 
Also randomForest is one of the most basic tree ensemble method. You should first verify that trees are build in the same way. To do so you can : 
1/ Do not Bootstrap
2/ Do not sample on column (mtry), 
3/ Fit only 1 tree.
See wether results are similar or not at this level.

Comment: @Romain Thank you very much for your reply! The default split criterion in Python random forest is indeed "gini". It is said that a criterion similar to gini gain is used in R. Please check the answer to this question which was posted here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144818/does-breimans-random-forest-use-information-gain-or-gini-index.

Comment: @Romain I followed your suggestion to do some testing. My finding is the outcome of a base tree in R and Python is same when minimum node size is set to 2 or 1 (of course, no sampling on predictors, build only one tree). But if I increased minimum node size to 15 or 30, the difference in AUC increases as well. Even if I tried to build 500 trees, the difference is still unavoidably huge (above 0.05 in AUC). BTW, for each model, I ran 50 simulations with same parameter setting but different random seeds. Then I took average value of the 50 simulations for each model.

Comment: @Romain Another finding is, the difference would be relatively smaller when bootstrapping is True. So I think the base tree implemented in R and in Python should NOT be exactly the same. Please feel free to let me know your concern or suggestion. thank you!